# How Kohana make chain between static and non-static?

Tags: php, oop, kohana

I'm not good in PHP and newbie in Kohana.

I'm very interesting how Kohana makes this structure: `Request::current()->controller()`. We call static method and then call non-static method.

How I can organise similar structure?

Comment: I guess that current() returns an instance of a certain class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Request::current()` will return an object, and you execute the `controller()` method on that object.

I understand you're confused with the use of static and non-static at the same time. It isn't confusing at all. Given these two classes:

```
static class StaticClass
{
    public function GetSomeObject
    {
        return new SomeObject();
    }
}

class SomeObject
{
    public function DoSomething()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

You can then initialize a SomeObject yourself, and execute its method:

```
$someObject = new SomeObject();
$someObject->DoSomething();
```

But it some cases this isn't desirable. I can imagine the `StaticClass` being some kind of repository (a singleton or factory for example), managing your `SomeObject` instances. You have to retreive all `SomeObject`s from the StaticClass. In this example this is done like this:

```
$someObject = StaticClass::GetSomeObject();
```

You can then again call the method:

```
$someObject->DoSomething();
```

The latter two can be written at once like this:

```
StaticClass::GetSomeObject()->DoSomething();
```

Comment: `public static $current; public static function current()
{
    return Request::$current;
}` I don't see that KO make new class instance

Comment: Then `Request::$current` is set somewhere else. It does return something, and given the code in your question, you execute `->controller()` on the `Request::$current` object. Please ask a clear question if something isn't clear to you yet.

Comment: FWIW for something that behaves similar take a look at the source code for the `Model::factory()` method:  https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/model.php